# ROOM Database: I can't autoGenerate my primary key

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

this is my code and I think it's 100% correct

```
@Serializable
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var userID: Int = 1,
    var fullName: String = "Missing",
    var email: String = "Missing",
    var password: String = "Missing",
    var phone: Long = -1,
    var profileImage: String = "Missing",
    var userType: Int = -1,
) {

    constructor(
        userID: Int = 1
    ) : this(
        fullName = "Missing",
        email = "Missing",
        password = "Missing",
        phone = -1,
        profileImage = "Missing",
        userType = -1,

        )
}
```

also, why `tableName & autoGenerate` not showing in blue color
[image]

Because the code was working for me before, but now I don't know why it doesn't work now

Comment: I removed them and still didn't work

Comment: Nothing when I checked the log is say adding user successful but when I checked the database only the first user have been added

Comment: same nothing changed

Comment: Add code of the DAO that you use for the insert and code where you actually call the insert.

Answer (score 0):

remove default id you've set in constructor, leave it for fulfil by database (when it autogenerate id for you)

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val userID: Int, // no = 1
```

also remove your second constructor and keep all your variables as final (thus `val`, not `var`)

edit: sample

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val userID: Int,
    val fullName: String = "Missing",
    val email: String = "Missing",
    val password: String = "Missing",
    val phone: Long = -1,
    val profileImage: String = "Missing",
    val userType: Int = -1,
)
```

Comment: How do you create the data class instance without it?(You can/have to have it there). (All of that you wrote reportedly doesn't work)

Comment: edited my answer, posted a sample (thats WHOLE code, no `{ }` body in there)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem

`userID: Int = 0` no 1

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var userID: Int = 0,
    var fullName: String = "Missing",
    var email: String = "Missing",
    var password: String = "Missing",
    var phone: Long = -1,
    var profileImage: String = "Missing",
    var userType: Int = -1,
) {

    constructor(
        userID: Int
    ) : this(
        userID,
        fullName = "Missing",
        email = "Missing",
        password = "Missing",
        phone = -1,
        profileImage = "Missing",
        userType = -1,
        )
}
```